# Independent set of relations in an algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $k⟨X⟩$ be a free associative algebra generated by a set $X$ over a field $k$. Let $S$ be a set of $k$-algebra relations. Then what does it mean by the set of relations are independent ?

Comment: I'd think it would mean that each $s \in S$ is not contained in the two-sided ideal generated by $S \setminus \{s\}$.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thanks for your reaction, I elaborated a bit in this direction, awaiting interaction with the OP

Comment: To the OP: The simple question of meaning is not of research level. The question of having efficient reduction procedures in presented algebras seems to be such, can you reword your question ?

Comment: To the OP: Thank you. I can help you to rephrase your question (or formulate another one) to the research level if you are interested because reduction of (associative) presentations is a very interesting subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you look $k<X>$ as a right module (over $k<X>$ itself) ? or a left-right bimodule ? (which seems to indicate $k$-algebra relations, look at the comment of Todd Trimble).

There is a theorem that I used many times to construct minimal automata (with multiplicities) and reduce the set of relations in a presented algebras, it is the following (th 3.2 p35 in Berstel and Reutenauer's book *Rational series and their languages* ,Monographs in Theoretical Computer Science. An EATCS Series, 1988). I can elaborate if you give me more contextual precisions (is the quotient finite-dimensional ?)

**Theorem** Let $I$ be a right ideal of $k<X>$ . There exists a prefix code
$C$ with associated prefix-closed set $P$, and coefficients 
$$
\alpha(c,p)\in k;\  (c \in  C, p \in P )
$$
 such that the polynomials 
 $$
 (P_c = c − \sum_{p\in P} \alpha(c,p) p) (c ∈ C) 
 $$
 generate freely $I$ as a right $k<X>$ -module and such that P defines a $k$-basis 
 in $k<X>/I$.
Is it what you are looking for ? (if this is the case, I can give algorithms)

Comment: If you mean merely $k$-linear relations, that doesn't sound quite right to me. See my comment above for what I would think is the correct formulation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I understood from your answer and Trimble's answer is that the set is minimal in the sense that no $s \in S$ is contained in the ideal generated by $S \setminus s$.

Comment: @Jacky OK, do not hesitate.